# Docker Cache being cleared when I COPY /

Tags: docker

I was trying to make my docker image build faster and noticed that the following step

```
# THIS STEP RUINS THE DOCKER CACHE, DON'T KNOW WHY
COPY / .
```

caused the cache to be invalidated. Is this happening because I'm changing the current repo in which I'm running the docker build in?

Can there a better way to only copy files of interest, perhaps with a regex.

Comment: Yes, any change in any file at all in your repository, including permissions or modification times, will invalidate the cache here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment below it seems that any change in the repo causes the docker cache to be cleared.

I suspect that

```
COPY / .
```

Rather than

```
COPY . .
```

is the reason the cache is being cleared, intentional of not.